# PHP binary image (id, blob binary data) array to Java script

Tags: javascript, php, binary, blob

I have an array in PHP with id and blob image binary data.

```
$mapImages = $mapImages."['".$row['_URI']."','".$imageRow['VALUE']."],";
```

When I echo this array into a java script variable:

```
var mapImages = [<?php echo $mapImages; ?>];
```

Java script breaks ... Finally I would like to use those ID's to properly place images on google maps.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, instead of building string yourself, you may consider [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: It echo's all id's and binary data on on IDE's console (Aptana), in chrome browser i get no output at all, seems like it is doing what it is supposed to do. However is there any way i can parse this php array (id, binary data) into JavaScript safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using base64 encode in php.

```
base64_encode($imageRow['VALUE'])
```

This would prepare binary values for safe echo/print into a javascript variable. Since this is already base64 encoded, we can generate image from it using  in following way.

```
"<img height='200' width='200' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,"+mapImages[valJ][1]+"'/>"
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Is there any browser that does not accept `data:image/*;base64,...`? This looks very interesting!

Comment: Its late but, I tested this on FF and Chrome, it works, can't say the same for IE

Comment: If what I read about "Data URLs" is correct and up to date, then IE supports it too. DataURLs seem really convenient!